# TS2604: JSX elemy type '' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I worked on my lazy load component's loader and got an error

> TS2604: JSX elemy type 'LoadedAsyncComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures

I think so I wrote a bad code and all, because I recently started writing on React + TypeScript chain

and it is my component:

```
import * as React from 'react';

declare interface AsyncComponentProps {
    moduleProvider: Function;
}
declare interface AsyncComponenState {
    LoadedAsyncComponent?: (React.Component<any, any> | null);
}

export class AsyncComponent extends React.Component<AsyncComponentProps, AsyncComponenState> {
    private isLoaded: boolean = false;
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            LoadedAsyncComponent: null
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        if (!this.isLoaded) {
            this.isLoaded = true;
            this.props.moduleProvider().then((provideData: any) => {
                this.setState({LoadedAsyncComponent: provideData[Object.keys(provideData)[0]] as React.Component});
            });
        }
    }
    render() {
        const {LoadedAsyncComponent} = this.state;
        return LoadedAsyncComponent ? <LoadedAsyncComponent/> : <div className="page-loading">Loading data</div>;
    }
}
```

Error is here:

```
return LoadedAsyncComponent ? <LoadedAsyncComponent/> : <div className="page-loading">Loading data</div>;
```

Also `moduleProvider` prop is a import promise:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ './Home/Home')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that problem when I changed that row:

```
return LoadedAsyncComponent ? <LoadedAsyncComponent/> : <div className="page-loading">Loading data</div>;
```

to:

```
return LoadedAsyncComponent ? React.createElement(LoadedAsyncComponent, {} as any) : <div className="page-loading">Loading data</div>;
```

and change type of `LoadedAsyncComponent` in state of `AsyncComponent` from `React.Component<any,any>` to `React.ComponentClass` and its worked for me for now...

Comment: Update: was needed only switch `LoadedAsyncComponent` type to `ComponentClass`
Also it worked too:
```return LoadedAsyncComponent ? <LoadedAsyncComponent/> : <div className="page-loading">Loading data</div>;```

Comment: @AluanHaddad just I think so that solution is not perfect. ComponentClass it is easier then Component. And AsyncComponent need for lazy loading routes